# Selenium dynamic id in xpath

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to select by xpath on products from this site https://www.crateandbarrel.ca/lindstrom-48x84-grey-curtain-panel/s557728

The xpaths look like this `//*[@id="react_0HM7S1A7EGQ26"]/div/div/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/div/div[2]/span/span/span` and CSS selectors like this `#react_0HM7S1A7EGQ26 > div > div > div.product-row.full-width > div.right-col > div.hidden-xs > div > div.shop-bar-price-area.jsProductPrice > span > span > span`

The `react_0HM7S1A7EGQ26` part is different on many products and I'm looking for a way to handle this.

Currently I'm doing something like this:

```
xpath = '//*[@id="react_0HM7S1A7EGQ26"]/div/div/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/div/div[2]/span/span/span'

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath))).text
```

However this xpath cannot be used for all products because the `0HM7S1A7EGQ26` changes.

Comment: @ArundeepChohan How do you have any hope of knowing what that might return given all those nested DIVs and SPANs??? If the page changes even in the slightest, it's very likely that locator will break. It's not a good practice to have such a generic XPath let alone such a long one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really not a good idea to use that large of an XPath or CSS selector. If the site changes at all the larger the locator, the more likely it will be that your locator will break.

It looks like you're trying to get the price

```
<div class="shop-bar-price-area jsProductPrice">
    <span>
        <span class="reg">
            <span class="regPrice">CAD 74.95</span>
        </span>
    </span>
</div>
```

You can get the price using a simple CSS selector, `span.regPrice`. The problem is that there are a TON of prices on the page for some reason... all of which are hidden except one. So to fix this, we can add code to use that locator and filter down to only the price that is visible.

```
prices = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("span.regPrice")
displayed_price = list(filter(lambda x: x.is_displayed(), prices))
print(displayed_price.text)
```

If you don't want to use all that, from my inspecting that one provided page it looks like the visible price is always the second element. You could try this and see if it works on all products you care about.

```
prices = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("span.regPrice")
print(prices[1].text)
```

Comment: You are great! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to check `id` few times, but looks like the `react_` part is immutable.
So you can simply catch it by partial id:

`"//*[contains(@id, "react_")]"`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I am not able to find which element you are searching for in the website.

Regarding `Xpath` you can use `contains` method like this -

xpath = `//*[contains(@id,"react_")]/div/div/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/div/div[2]/span/span/span`

Do let me know if it helps.

Comment: I'm trying to select the price. I see all the prices have a class of `regPrice`. I tried to select with `WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'regPrice'))).text` but it times out

Comment: `All_Prices = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'regPrice')))`
Then loop through the element and extract text.
`for price in All_Prices:
    print(price.text)`